# How to build static website by parsing pug, sass and js into final html, css and js2015?

Tags: javascript, sass, static, pug

I've done some Node.js work, but now some "client" has asked me to make a static page like to be hosted on GitHub gh-pages, and have some static navigation but I want to build it with pug, sass, and js. I've tried with some webpack configurations but version 4 seems to be having problems with some of the plugins. Any idea, project, generator or anything would be appreciated.

Thanks. Alex

For example, i've come up with this webpack config, if anyone can make it better would be really nice.

```
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          publicPath: '/dist'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?name=[name].html',
          'pug-html-loader?pretty&exports=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: false,
    port: 3030,
    stats: 'errors-only'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: something like this https://prepros.io/ but I want to build that workflow on my computer so do that I learn how to do it.

Comment: did you figure out how to?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use command line tools, via scripts in package.json. Here's an example

```
"scripts":{
    "start": "http-server -o -c-1",
    "build-sass": "node-sass scss/style.scss style.css",
    "watch-sass": "npm run build-sass && onchange 'scss/*' -- npm run build-sass",
    "watch-js": "watchify js/main.js -o bundle.js -v",
    "build-js": "browserify js/main.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ] | uglifyjs -c -m > bundle.js",
    "build": "npm run build-sass && npm run build-js",
    "dev": "npm run watch-sass & npm run watch-js & npm start"
},
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.9",
    "watchify": "^3.10.0"
}
```

For a big project you might want something more complicated, but this works for me most of the time.

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick but I'm looking for something more robust.